# Network International Payment Sdk for NGenious showing error

Tags: android, kotlin, payment-gateway

I am working on NGenious payment SDK and trying to implement it in my Kotlin project but when the SDK shows up in Fragment, after 2 to 3 seconds the screen automatically got white and nothing is being shown.

[This](https://github.com/network-international/payment-sdk-android) is the payment SDK

Method to launch payment Fragment

```
            activity?.let {
                PaymentClient(it).launchCardPayment(
                    CardPaymentRequest.builder()
                        .gatewayUrl(paymentOption.paymentCreateOrderResponse.data?.links?.paymentAuthorization?.href?:"")
                        .code(Constants.currencyCode)
                        .build(), CARD_PAYMENT_REQUEST_CODE)
            }
```

`onActivityResult` Method

```
override fun onActivityResult(
    requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    Log.e("onActivityResult","onActivityResult" + resultCode)
    if (requestCode == CARD_PAYMENT_REQUEST_CODE) {
        when (resultCode) {
            Activity.RESULT_OK -> onCardPaymentResponse(CardPaymentData.getFromIntent(data!!))
            Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> onCardPaymentCancelled()
        }
        Log.e("resultCode CCPF","" + resultCode)
    }
    Log.e("CPRC CCPF","" + CARD_PAYMENT_REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I review your CardPaymentRequest builder you are sending the Currency Code in the code field thats why they throwing an exception on it.

pass payment code in the code field, you can get the code by this field.

```
paymentOption.paymentCreateOrderResponse.data?.links?.payment?.href?.split("=")!!.get(1)
```

Now run the code like that.

```kotlin
activity?.let {
    PaymentClient(it).launchCardPayment(request = CardPaymentRequest.builder()
            .gatewayUrl(paymentOption.paymentCreateOrderResponse.data?.links?.paymentAuthorization?.href?:"")
            .code(paymentOption.paymentCreateOrderResponse.data?.links?.payment?.href?.split("=")!!.get(1))
            .build(), requestCode = CARD_PAYMENT_REQUEST_CODE)
}
```